# Кривые формы слов в истории тревог

Tags: дефект, локализация, тревоги

Справа норм:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В заголовке нет:

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/305001/339911